# UIPickerView depending on UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uipickerview

I don't have much experience in programming, so here is my question:

I'm trying to write a converter app. At the end, you can enter a number. Then I have a two component `UIPickerView`. With the first component, you select the input format (e.x. °Celcius). With the second component, you select the output format (e.x. °Fahrenheit), in order to convert °Celcius into °Fahrenheit.

But I want to add more units (weight, energy etc.). I want them to display on a `UITableView`. If I select a certain cell in the `UITableView`, the `UIPickerView` has to update its delegate. More precisely, the array in which I have the names of the units (e.x. eV, Joule, cal, erg, etc...) must be somehow implemented in the `detailViewController` (where I have my `UIPickerView`).

Here's my code:

### ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate>

@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *EinheitenPicker;
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *EinheitenTableView;

@end
```

### ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"


@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSArray *EinheitenNameArray;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize EinheitenPicker,EinheitenTableView;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    EinheitenNameArray=[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"AlleEinheiten" ofType:@"plist"]];

    [self.EinheitenTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];

    [self.EinheitenTableView.delegate tableView:self.EinheitenTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark UItableView Delegate
- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return EinheitenNameArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"CellId";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if(cell==nil) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text=[[EinheitenNameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Titel"];

    return cell;
}


- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    //NSLog(@"Chosen:%@",self.EinheitenPicker);

    [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TestId"];

    [self.EinheitenPicker reloadAllComponents];
}

#pragma mark UIPickerView Methods

- (NSInteger) numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath=[self.EinheitenTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSArray *units=[[EinheitenNameArray objectAtIndex:selectedIndexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Einheiten"];

    if (component == 0) {
        return units.count;
    }

    return units.count;   
}

- (NSString*) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath=[self.EinheitenTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSArray *units=[[EinheitenNameArray objectAtIndex:selectedIndexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Einheiten"];
    return [units objectAtIndex:row];
}

@end
```

Comment: Only use the [tag:xcode] tag for questions about the IDE itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If I am not wrong you are looking for something like this.

[image]

To have it so you must implement UIPickerView methods as follows

```
-(NSInteger) numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{

    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath=[self.unitsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSArray *units=[[unitDataArray objectAtIndex:selectedIndexPath.section] objectForKey:@"units"];
    return units.count;
}

-(NSString*) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath=[self.unitsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSArray *units=[[unitDataArray objectAtIndex:selectedIndexPath.section] objectForKey:@"units"];
    return [units objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

In **UITableView Delegate** you can reload the picker View  as follows.

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [self.unitPicker reloadAllComponents];
}
```

To create the items for **Table which has components as well units** , you can use .plist file as follows

[image]

To help you with UITableView Methods I am adding the required code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    unitDataArray=[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:<Name of plist File> ofType:@"plist"]];
    [self.unitsTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
    [self.unitsTableView.delegate tableView:self.unitsTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
}

-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return unitDataArray.count;
}

-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    NSDictionary *unitData=[unitDataArray objectAtIndex:section];
    return [[unitData objectForKey:@"units"] count];
}

-(UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"CellId";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if(cell==nil){
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text=[[[unitDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"units"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

-(NSString*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    NSDictionary *unitData=[unitDataArray objectAtIndex:section];
    return [unitData objectForKey:@"title"];
}


-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [self.unitPicker reloadAllComponents];
}
```

**CHANGES**
If you want it to show as displayed below, minor tweaks to my code is required.

[image]

```
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize unitPicker,unitsTableView;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    unitDataArray=[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"AllUnits" ofType:@"plist"]];
    [self.unitsTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
    [self.unitsTableView.delegate tableView:self.unitsTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark UItableView Delegate
-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;//Changes 1
}

-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return unitDataArray.count;//Changes 2
}

-(UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"CellId";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if(cell==nil){
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text=[[unitDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];

    return cell;
}


-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [self.unitPicker reloadAllComponents];
}

#pragma mark UIPicker View Methods

-(NSInteger) numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
    return 1;//Changes 3
}

-(NSInteger) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{

    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath=[self.unitsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSArray *units=[[unitDataArray objectAtIndex:selectedIndexPath.row] objectForKey:@"units"];//Changes 4
    return units.count;
}

-(NSString*) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath=[self.unitsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSArray *units=[[unitDataArray objectAtIndex:selectedIndexPath.row] objectForKey:@"units"];//Changes 5
    return [units objectAtIndex:row];
}




@end
```

**Header File** is quite simple too.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate>
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *unitPicker;
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *unitsTableView;
@end
```

Please find the [Demo project here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ktezxztfok0ifrf/ZPuUzoowvh/UnitSelection%202.zip)

Comment: Thank you so much!
Could you please show the header-file, as I have some troubles with the implementation.
@andyPaul

Comment: Ur welcome, let me know if you need anything else. If have you any troubles please ask.

Comment: Thanks for answering!
I still have 3 small questions:
- Is there no need to implement the unitDataArray somewhere (as it is not in the h-file)?
- How do you connect everything in the xib-file?
- And would it also be possible to create everything using Storyboard, where the UIPicker and the UITableView are not in the same View?

You're a great help to me, thanks a lot and sorry for being an absolut beginner, I started 2 month ago and for me it's very complicated!
@andyPaul

Comment: Ur welcome Mr. absolute beginner , i have now attached a demo project for you with this email, hope that helps you to learn things on connection and other stuff.

Comment: I still have a tiny problem: I want the UIPickerView in another `ViewController`. Do I have to use a `prepareForSegue`-method? @andyPaul

Comment: You can use prepareForSegue but instead of that use [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View Controller Storyboard Id"]; This will get you the UIViewController in storyboard file. Once you have it set the frame of the view and add then add it to view of your current controller.

Comment: so I simply write [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"<a certain Identifier>"]; into my didSelectRowAtIndexPath-method? Then I create a new ViewController in Storyboard, with a push-segue from my UITableView?
@andyPaul

Comment: no push-segue is not required here now. just drag a UIViewController in storyboard, set the StoryboardId thats it. Use that id in  [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"<a certain Identifier>"]

Comment: is there no simple solution? @andyPaul

Comment: I don't know, why you are not able to get it,As commented before You are not doing what i have said. Repeating Again "[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View Controller Storyboard Id"], this will give you are UIViewController. A UIViewController has a UIView , you set the frame of a UIView object. and Then add it to your current ViewController(view in ViewController.m)".. You have just obtained a UIViewController from [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TestId"] but not using it.

Comment: could you upload a demo-file, as I have some tremendous problems with the Interface-Builder a linking everything together? @andyPaul

Comment: I searched for hours and I haven't seen any solution to my problem: I just want that the UITableView and the UIPickerView are NOT in the same View. Is there a simple solution? @andyPaul